# My docker-compose.yml couldn't build mysql5.7 container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml, mysql-5.7

I'm trying to build docker container for laravel with docker-compose.yml.

I hove to build database container for mysql5.7.
Mysql8 cannot be used on my server witch connected.

There is my docker-compose.yml file.

```
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: ./docker/php
      args:
        - TZ=${TZ}
    ports:
      - ${APP_PORT}:8000
    volumes:
      - ${PROJECT_PATH}:/work
      - ./docker/ash:/etc/profile.d
      - ./docker/php/psysh:/root/.config/psysh
      - ./logs:/var/log/php
      - ./docker/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
    working_dir: /work
    environment:
      - DB_CONNECTION=mysql
      - DB_HOST=db
      - DB_DATABASE=${DB_NAME}
      - DB_USERNAME=${DB_USER}
      - DB_PASSWORD=${DB_PASS}
      - TZ=${TZ}
      - MAIL_HOST=${MAIL_HOST}
      - MAIL_PORT=${MAIL_PORT}
      - CACHE_DRIVER=redis
      - SESSION_DRIVER=redis
      - QUEUE_DRIVER=redis
      - REDIS_HOST=redis

  web:
    image: nginx:1.17-alpine
    depends_on:
      - app
    ports:
      - ${WEB_PORT}:80
    volumes:
      - ${PROJECT_PATH}:/work
      - ./logs:/var/log/nginx
      - ./docker/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    environment:
      - TZ=${TZ}

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - db-store:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./logs:/var/log/mysql
      - ./docker/mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${DB_NAME}
      - MYSQL_USER=${DB_USER}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${DB_PASS}
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${DB_PASS}
      - TZ=${TZ}
    ports:
      - ${DB_PORT}:3306

  db-testing:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - ./docker/mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf
    tmpfs:
      - /var/lib/mysql
      - /var/log/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${DB_NAME}
      - MYSQL_USER=${DB_USER}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${DB_PASS}
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${DB_PASS}
      - TZ=${TZ}
    ports:
      - ${DB_TESTING_PORT}:3306

  node:
    image: node:12.13-alpine
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - ${PROJECT_PATH}:/work
    working_dir: /work

  redis:
    image: redis:5.0-alpine
    volumes:
      - redis-store:/data

  mail:
    image: mailhog/mailhog
    ports:
      - ${MAILHOG_PORT}:8025

volumes:
  db-store:
  redis-store:
```

When I execute "docker-compose build" in terminal, it's successfully done, but db container and db-testing container has status "EXIT: 1" or "EXIT: 2".
So, Could you teach me what's wrong.

Comment: You should show us the error/log messages

Comment: Your volume entries must use the absolute paths (no ./).